# EF: Group a GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of class `UserHit` that should be grouped by `Date`and than by the `UserGuid`.

```
var list = db.UserHits
             .GroupBy(x => x.UtcTimeStamp.Day               // work around because 
                         + x.UtcTimeStamp.Month * 100       // EF does not 
                         + x.UtcTimeStamp.Year * 100 * 100) // support .Date property
             .GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault().UserGuid)
             .ToDictionary(x => x.FirstOrDefault()
                                 .FirstOrDefault()
                                 .UtcTimeStamp.Date, 
                           x => Tuple.Create(x.Count(), x.Sum(y => y.Count())));
```

When I execute this stement, I get the following exception:

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

I found out that this error can occur with some Select-Where statements but I found out nothing about a nested grouping.

Comment: Nested groupby on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx

Comment: @user238905 Not LINQ is the pProblem, the EF is...